# Permanently mounting a directory with LVM

Tags: filesystems, mount, lvm, fstab

I successfully mounted a directory to another path:

```
[michael@vps ~]$ mkdir /home/michael/devicefilexxx
[michael@vps ~]$ mkdir /home/michael/mountpointxxx
[michael@vps ~]$ sudo mount --bind /home/michael/devicefilexxx /home/michael/mountpointxxx
```

I see how it looks:

```
[michael@vps ~]$ cat /etc/mtab | grep xxx
/dev/mapper/centos-root /home/michael/mountpointxxx xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
```

Well, the mount point looks correct, but not the device.  I specified the device as `/home/michael/devicefilexxx`, not `/dev/mapper/centos-root`.  So I look a little deeper:

```
[michael@vps ~]$ mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
devtmpfs on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,size=1009596k,nr_inodes=252399,mode=755)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,mode=755)
tmpfs on /sys/fs/cgroup type tmpfs (ro,nosuid,nodev,noexec,mode=755)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,xattr,release_agent=/usr/lib/systemd/systemd-cgroups-agent,name=systemd)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/pids type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,pids)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/net_cls,net_prio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,net_prio,net_cls)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpu,cpuacct type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuacct,cpu)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/perf_event type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,perf_event)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/devices type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,devices)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/blkio type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,blkio)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/cpuset type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,cpuset)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/memory type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,memory)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/freezer type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,freezer)
cgroup on /sys/fs/cgroup/hugetlb type cgroup (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,hugetlb)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/mapper/centos-root on / type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=34,pgrp=1,timeout=300,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
tmpfs on /run/user/1000 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=204060k,mode=700,uid=1000,gid=1000)
/dev/mapper/centos-root on /home/michael/mountpointxxx type xfs (rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota)
```

Hmm, two devices at the same mount point?  So, I look at my `/etc/fstab`:

```
[michael@vps ~]$ cat /etc/fstab

#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Fri Apr  8 14:15:42 2016
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk'
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info
#
/dev/mapper/centos-root /                       xfs     defaults        1 1
UUID=362355d4-e5da-44de-bf5c-5ce92cf43888 /boot                   xfs     defaults        1 2
/dev/mapper/centos-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

If I wish to make the mount persistent after the machine is rebooted, surely I wouldn't want to add the following to `/etc/stab`:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root /home/michael/mountpointxxx xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
```

Maybe the following, but I hesitate to do so as it differs from what `/etc/mtab` told me:

```
/home/michael/devicefilexxx /home/michael/mountpointxxx xfs rw,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota 0 0
```

How does one permanently mount a directory/file?  Also, please explain how `/dev/mapper/centos-root` can have two mount points which are obviously different so must be mounted to different devices.

EDIT.  Backup info:

```
[michael@vps ~]$ lsblk
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda               8:0    0   80G  0 disk
├─sda1            8:1    0  500M  0 part /boot
└─sda2            8:2    0 79.5G  0 part
  ├─centos-swap 253:0    0    2G  0 lvm  [SWAP]
  └─centos-root 253:1    0 77.5G  0 lvm  /
sr0              11:0    1 1024M  0 rom
[michael@lsblk ~]$
```

Comment: Is the part about using LVM very interesting here? Isn't this mostly about how a bind mount looks confusing in the output of `mount` and in `/proc/mounts`? And I don't think you have two devices with the same mount point, just the same device with two mount points, which again is what will show up with bind mounts, right?

Comment: @ilkkachu.  I agree they are definitely two different mount point.  I think I am confused on what is a `device`.  Does it not constitute a path?  If so, wouldn't they be two different devices (i.e. `/` and `/home/michael/devicefilexxx`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try for the `/dev/mapper/centos-root`, your using what in Linux is called Logical Volume Management. This acts like a wrapper around your filesystem making it easy to adjust when compared to the normal partitions. You have three main mount points, root as seen from your /etc/fstab:

- `/`, `swap` and `/boot`

So boot stuff is in `/boot`, and swap `RAM` in `swap`. Every other part of your filesystem is found in `/`, and this is mapped to `dev/mapper/centos-root`.

Mine is:

```
NAME            FSTYPE      LABEL                       UUID                                   MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                                                            
|-sda1          xfs                                     f86877f2-5099-483f-a56b-24a772cf4863   /boot
`-sda2          LVM2_member                             uw2D4k-IsO3-0u2N-dKLz-utuC-tDn8-zwtaDT 
  |-centos-root xfs                                     e3faa70d-fc88-4951-8122-789e21a519f7   /
  |-centos-swap swap                                    95eaf3bb-7b78-418d-b14d-74206d89b3d9   [SWAP]
  |-centos-var  xfs                                     c35276a4-f8e2-4982-91fe-b0cd205601ff   /var
  `-centos-home xfs                                     c09e81c2-32e9-4ebd-a59b-caf57971a069   /home
```

And as you can see I the same names to yours but I also created other partions to map to different areas of my CentOS.

And my `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/mapper/centos-root /                       xfs     defaults        0 0
UUID=f86877f2-5099-483f-a56b-24a772cf4863 /boot xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/centos-home /home                   xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/centos-var  /var                    xfs     defaults        0 0
/dev/mapper/centos-swap swap                    swap    defaults        0 0
```

So long story short, the mount your creating is in the `/` root partion hence it will be mapped to `/dev/mapper/centos-root`. That's the way it aught to be.

To permanently mount those folders add this line to your `/etc/fstab` file. Of course, make a backup of the original in case you make a mistake.

```
/home/michael/devicefilexxx /home/michael/mountpointxxx none bind 0  0
```

To see a more detailed mount point schema use the command: `findmnt`

Comment: Thank you George,  How would one mount a device and determine where it was mounted since `/etc/mtab` shows differently?  Also, why isn't `swap` shown by the `mount` output?  Maybe asking too many unrelated questions, so I better shut up :)  Thanks.  By the way, I added my `lsblk` at the bottom of the original post (note that it is a vps hosted by 1&1).

Comment: Ignore `/etc/mtab` that should not concern you, what should is what is in `/etc/fstab`. I added the solution to the answer see the bottom. Swap isn't mounted anywhere that for system memory swapping and the like. It's meant for your system to us.  To see what is mount i more detail run `findmnt`

Comment: Ah, `findmnt`.  That, and not `/etc/mtab` was what I was looking for!  Thanks.  So, I manually mounted the directory (not using fstab yet), and `findmnt` shows `/home/jail/home/pubuser/repo         /dev/mapper/centos-root[/home/michael/pubuser/repo] xfs        ro,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota`.  So, that means `/home/michael/pubuser/repo /home/jail/home/pubuser/repo xfs ro,relatime,attr2,inode64,noquota` goes in `/etc/fstab`?  PS.  Fully acknowledge your previous legal disclaimer about making a backup first :)